# update rows one by one with max value + 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor

here is my situation,
I have 2 tables, 
1st table has all records, and it has IDs
2nd table has new records and it doesnt have ID, yet.
I want to generate ID for 2nd table with max(id) + 1 from 1st table.
when i do this, it makes all rows same id number, but i want to make it unique increment number.
e.g
select max(id) from table1   then it gives  '997040'
I want to make second table rows like;

id
997041
997042
997043
997044

i think i need to use cursor or whileloop, or both, but i could not create the actual query.
sorry about bad explanation, i am so confused now

Comment: Which database? With Oracle, you can add ROWNUM to the result.

Comment: in T-SQL, actually you are right, let me try rownum

Comment: thank you very much, i dont know why i couldnt see this way, i was stuck with cursor etc. it worked with rownum.

Answer (score 1):

Use ROWNUM to generate incrementing row numbers. E.g.:

```
SELECT someConstant + ROWNUM FROM source.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
ID int IDENTITY(997041,1) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

I hope this sql query would work!!
Or refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp